# Simple time helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am building a simple event system and i am having problem with rails time helper conversions. I want to be able to have a 12hour clock that has an output of something like 12:00am or 12:00pm using something like `<%= event.start_at %>` to give the time output in the 12hour clock format

Comment: What's the 12 hour clock format? Do you mean converting from 24-hour time to 12-hour time?

Comment: @Dave Newton yes including the am and pm signs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime

Answer (score 3):

If `event.start_at` is already a date or time object (e.g. an ActiveRecord instance) then you could do something like:

```
<%= event.start_at.to_s(:my_format) %>
```

You'd need to define `:my_format` in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/date_and_time_formats.rb
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:my_format] = '%I:%M%P' # 12:30pm
```

You can tweak the format to your liking and use it over and over again using `to_s(:my_format)`. [@Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton) pointed out where to go for formatting [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409518/simple-time-helper-in-rails/7409772#7409772).

Comment: This is so cool. thanks a lot it helps too. i use to wonder if those `%I:%M%P` were formulated by people all i use to do the was just test it and read the output but thanks to @dave newton link i now no were they are all coming from. Thanks ones again for this global method